# Proxy tunneling failed: Invalid request -- HOST header was not sent Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: ssl, proxy, wget

wget fails to download through a proxy server with the following message: **Invalid request -- HOST header was not sentUnable to establish SSL connection.**

Example:

```
[root@foosrv0234ccpra ~]# wget https://packages.chef.io/stable/el/6/chefdk-0.18.26-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
--2016-09-27 16:57:44--  https://packages.chef.io/stable/el/6/chefdk-0.18.26-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Resolving deehprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com (deehprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com)... 129.35.62.40
Connecting to deehprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com (deehprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com)|129.35.62.40|:8080... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Invalid request -- HOST header was not sentUnable to establish SSL connection.

[root@foosrv0234ccpra ~]# env|grep proxy
http_proxy=http://barsrvprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com:8080
https_proxy=http://barsrvprx024ccpxa.ehn.sr.dev.sdc.mycomp.com:8080
no_proxy=barsrvacp014ccpra,barsrvchf014ccpra.ssm.sdc.gts.mycomp.com,localhost,127.0.0.1,barsrvacp014ccpra.ssm.sdc.gts.mycomp.com
```

It took me a while to get through this, so I'm sharing the issue on StackOverflow. Please have a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above happens because `HTTP 1.1` requires the client to provide a HOST header and the proxy server does not support `HTTP 1.1` (refer to RFC 2616 for more details on this requirement).

Some alternatives:

- Upgrade your proxy to support HTTP 1.1
- Downgrade `wget` to a version that only supports HTTP 1.0 (wget v1.12 or below)
- Find another way to force all HTTP calls to be made using 1.0 and not 1.1 (I haven't explore this possibility and I'm not sure how to do it... downgrading wget solved my issue)